# How to automate uploading photos to a website?

Tags: python

For the website 'https://web-en.wallapop.com/catalog/upload', if one tries to upload an add and scrolls down, photos can also be uploaded. How would I automate the uploading of a photo to this website with python?

I am currently writing a program that automatically creates adds on this website, however I do not know how to automate the uploading of a photo, located in my repository, to the website. I need to interact with the file explorer to pick the image and I do not know how to automate that. I do not even know if that is the right approach.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/tsl-root/tsl-upload/div/div/tsl-upload-product/form/div[2]/tsl-drop-area/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/label/input').send_keys(r'C:\Users\Nicolas Sanchez\3D Objects\Freelancer\Alberto\imagenes\i1473749533.jpg')
```

This works. This was my first thought initially however I was picking the wrong xpath selectors. This is the right xpath selector.